# Redis connection: Received error "dial tcp [::1]:6379: connect: connection refused" when attempting to Dial with Redigo

Tags: database, go, redis, redigo

I'm trying to run

```
conn, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

using redis Redigo, the golang driver. I have not changed any configurations or anything. My error is:

```
go run redisgotest.go
2019/11/19 15:51:05 dial tcp [::1]:6379: connect: connection refused
exit status 1
```

Comment: The error is returned from the net package dial function when there is no listener for the specified address.  There may be other scenarios where this error is returned.

Comment: How do you run Redis? Can you connect to it using other client?

Comment: Is your local redis instance running?